# Creating a Yeoman generator and have it be version controlled

Tags: node.js, yeoman, yeoman-generator

I'm wrapping my head around creating a Yeoman generator, so that Yeoman can generate our boilerplate whenever a new project is started.

The building blocks of this boilerplate should be version controlled. So I assume the generator (which will contain the rules for creating the boilerplate) should be hosted on github.

Which leads me to the question: if the generator itself is hosted on github, how will Yeoman save me any time? Because in order to use the latest version of the generator I would have to pull it off off github anyhow (which I could just as well do with the boilerplate itself, if it were hosted on github).

Or am I misunderstanding where a Yeoman generator is located? Because as I understand it you have to have it locally, or use one of the generators from the public repo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can quite easily publish it to npm using the command `npm publish`. Then you can install and upgrade it just like any other npm module. I did it myself for my first Yeoman generator and it's pretty straightforward.

[This is a good place to start](https://www.npmjs.org/doc/misc/npm-developers.html).

Comment: Ah! So if I understand correctly: the generator can be published to npm and if it is then installed, it will grab the actual content from a git repo (which will take care of any version control)?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. When you create a new release, you just amend the version number in `package.json`, commit and push the changes, then publish them. Then users can just update their Node modules as usual.